# Dialog delegate directive state not changing

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am running into an issue where the dialog state is not changing after I use the `Dialog.Delegate`. I fulfill all of the slot values in the test, but my it just says I have an error in the response and it says the dialog is still in progress. I am wondering how I would fix this.  Here is the piece of the code that I have to call the delegate:

```
return  handlerInput.responseBuilder
    .addDelegateDirective(currentIntent)
    .getResponse()
```

Comment: Can you post the request and response ?

Comment: This is the response after I enter the value for the last slot value that is needed. Shouldn't the dialog state be completed after it obtains the last slot?  Here is the JSON request:

Comment: request": {
  "type": "IntentRequest",
  "requestId": "amzn1.echo-api.request.3064a352-59fc-4fc9-a325-5d5d7e6ad777",
  "timestamp": "2018-05-02T21:54:15Z",
  "locale": "en-US",
  "intent": {
   "name": "getInfo",
   "confirmationStatus": "NONE",
   "slots": {
    "firstName": {
     "name": "firstName",
     "value": "Noah",
     "confirmationStatus": "NONE"
    },
    "lastName": {
     "name": "lastName",
     "value": "Woodward",
     "confirmationStatus": "NONE"
    }
   }
  },
  "dialogState": "IN_PROGRESS"
 }
}

Comment: {
 "body": {
  "version": "1.0",
  "response": {
   "directives": [
    {
     "type": "Dialog.Delegate"
    }
   ]
  },
  "sessionAttributes": {},
  "userAgent": "ask-node/2.0.2 Node/v6.10.3"
 }
}